# Can't push/pull to bitbucket via SSH using IPv6

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, vpn, ipv6

**When I can push/pull to bitbucket:**

- From my work computer via ssh key `id_rsa_bitbucket_work`
- From my laptop, but only when logged into VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) via ssh key `id_rsa_bitbucket`. My VPN has a static IP.
- Always using https.

**When I cannot push/pull to bitbucket:**

- From my laptop anytime VPN is not connected, via ssh key `ida_rsa_bitbucket`.
- From my laptop on my work network network when not on VPN, even though I'm nominally on the same network I would be with VPN.

**The appropriate entry in my `~/.ssh/config` is:**

```
Host bitbucket
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
```

Connecting to github repositories via SSH always works, regardless of what network/VPN I am going through.

**I have checked to make sure that:**

- My SSH agent is running and has the correct keys loaded.
- My SSH agent is handing out the same key regardless of VPN settings.

**The output from `ssh -Tv bitbucket` when NOT logged in to VPN is:**

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/fcarter/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/fcarter/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2401:1d80:1010::150] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/fcarter/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/fcarter/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.284-7b46313 app-127
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.284-7b46313 app-127
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/fcarter/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/fcarter/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([2401:1d80:1010::150]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 4048, received 1776 bytes, in 10.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 401.8, received 176.3
debug1: Exit status -1
```

It appears to connect and authenticate (via IPv6?), but exits with an error.

**The output from `ssh -Tv bitbucket` when logged into my VPN is:**

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/fcarter/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/fcarter/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2401:1d80:1010::151] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 2401:1d80:1010::151 port 22: Permission denied
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/fcarter/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/fcarter/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.284-7b46313 app-125
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.284-7b46313 app-125
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/fcarter/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/fcarter/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([104.192.143.3]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
logged in as faustin315.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 4048, received 1984 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 16284.6, received 7981.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

It appears to connect and authenticate (via IPv4?) and everything is fine.

**Update:**
After finding [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12184/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucketorg-port-443) on bitbucket's site, I tried adding `104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org` to my `/etc/hosts` file. This did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Updated after lots of help from Bitbucket support:**

After much more research, the problem appears to be on my router's end (Linksys E3200) and is somehow related to IPv6. I have no trouble accessing IPv6-only sites, and everything works fine with github (this is because github is IPv4 only). However, there is something being filtered out that SSH needs to work properly. If I jack directly into my modem and run `ssh -Tvv bitbucket` it authenticates properly over IPv6.

In order to work around the problem (while I shop for a new router), I am forcing connections to bitbucket to only use IPv4 by adding `AddressFamily inet` to my `~/.ssh/config file` (thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35113901/7735643). So the updated entry for bitbucket now reads:

```
Host bitbucket
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
     AddressFamily inet
```

Comment: I'd just moved house and changed internet supplier. This was causing me considerable irritation, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Wow. I spent months trying to solve this. In my case, my guess is that my Internet provider (Claro ARG) was blocking the IPv6 traffic at the router level. I use your solution but I add also bitbucket.org as a separate host with the same config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If somebody needs this maybe adding (on answer above):

...
ConnectTimeout 10
...

can help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `104.192.141.1 bitbucket.org` in `/etc/hosts` as an entry worked for me as mentioned in [this official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/connecting-to-bitbucket-org-over-ipv6-840796883.html).