# cannot install private python package with git

Tags: python, git, github, pip, bitbucket

I am trying to install a private python package from a bitbucket repo with sshkeys by using following command

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/package.git
```

but i am getting following error.

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:pak-sign: Name or
>   service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. Command "git clone -q
>   ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/package.git
>   /tmp/pip-7j4r53en-build" failed with error code 128 in None

but when i try to clone this repo ssh is working fine and i am able to clone it successfully. I am sure that my ssh-keys are correct and repository exists. I have tried various solutions but still not able to install it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bitbucket can't pull/push from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747969/bitbucket-cant-pull-push-from-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo` format does not work when the `git+ssh://` scheme is specified. (With `git+ssh://` present, SSH will assume that the stuff behind the colon is a port number.) Instead, use a slash between `bitbucket.org` and the rest of the path:

`git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/package.git`

Comment: Weirdly, i pushed a repo to my org's bitbucket account and if i use my username, it didn't work, but worked with using org instead of my username in aforementioned format. There should be a manual for this :( .

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your DNS as [Google Public DNS IP addresses](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#google_public_dns_ip_addresses) :

The Google Public DNS IP addresses (IPv4) are as follows:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

The Google Public DNS IPv6 addresses are as follows:

```
2001:4860:4860::8888
2001:4860:4860::8844
```

Check the Documentation for more details : [How to Change your DNS servers settings](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#change_your_dns_servers_settings)